# JOIN Only if One Matching Record in both tables

Tags: mysql

Essentially I need to only LEFT JOIN on the 2 tables if there is one `customerid` matching in `table2`. If there is more than 1 record matching `table2` it should not count as a match.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    table1.customerid,
    table1.name AS customer,
    table2.locationid,
    table2.locationname
FROM
    table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.customerid = table2.customerid
WHERE
ORDER BY
    name ASC
```

The issue is it matches on all records.

To clarify -- if customerid is in table2 more than once, it should not join on the match, only if customerid is listed once for a record in table2.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that only returns customer IDs that have count = 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    table1.customerid,
    table1.name AS customer,
    table2.locationid,
    table2.locationname
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT customerid, MAX(locationid) AS locationid, MAX(locationname) AS locationname
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY customerid
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS table2 ON table1.customerid = table2.customerid
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Note that using `LEFT JOIN` means that if `locationid` is not in `table2` at all, the query will still return a row for that location, with `NULL` in the `table2` fields. And with this change, it will also return those null rows when there's more than 1 matching row. If you want those rows omitted from the results entirely, use `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I seem to get the following error `Unknown column 'table2.customerid' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Sorry, that should be `customerid` in the subquery